# Best way to build project with plugins that use UnityEditor namespace?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my project but have 261 errors due to the UnityEditor namespace. These are all in plugins though, with their separate assemblies. I can't just put all these scripts in an "Editor" folder. What's the best way to proceed?

replacing `using UnityEditor` with `#if UNITY_EDITOR  using UnityEditor; #endif`
just breaks it even more.

Comment: Put them in a folder called Editor. Like it says to.  Or. You have to out that round all editor code.

Comment: Only option I can think of is to make separate assemblies out of your `Editor` scripts